# Update style of already rendered webpage by using js to load a css stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to load some CSS file into a page that has already been loaded and rendered by the browser and apply it's styling to the page without reloading it as a whole.

I can't modify the original page too much, so the CSS has to be linked/included in the html at a later moment using JavaScript. I tried adding a `<link>` element referring to the CSS file in the header, as well as adding `<style>` with the CSS itself.

The modification of the html does work fine, but the layout of the page isn't affected at all. Probably because the browser doesn't re-render the page at this point?

I saw some answers here suggesting that it would work like described above, but for me it does nothing. What could be the reason here?

---

As requested, some of the JavaScript i'm using to update the HTML of the page. Both ways work fine, the elements are added to the page. So I presume the error lies somewhere else.

1.) Adding actual CSS by reading it with XHR from file:

```
var promptCSS= document.createElement('style'); 
promptCSS.type="text/css";
var cssPromptFileSelectStyleURL= 'promptFileSelectStyle.css';
//add css of prompt into current page html
var cssFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    cssFile.open("GET",cssPromptFileSelectStyleURL,true);
    cssFile.send();

 cssFile.onreadystatechange =       function(){

if (cssFile.readyState== 4 && cssFile.status == 200){
promptCSS.innerHTML=cssFile.responseText;
}};


var head=document.querySelectorAll("head")[0];
head.appendChild(promptCSS);
```

2.) adding `<link>` referencing CSS file

```
var promptCSS= document.createElement('link');
promptCSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
promptCSS.type = 'text/css';
promptCSS.href = 'promptFileSelectStyle.css';
var head=document.querySelectorAll("head")[0];
head.appendChild(promptCSS);
```

Comment: try to post (code) what you have done so far, much easier to understand and help

Answer (score 2):

Inline CSS isn't set between `<script>` tags, but between `<style>` tags.

Also here is a Fiddle that tests your method : https://jsfiddle.net/sLpfLsLc/

It waits 2 seconds before loading a new CSS file containing

```
*{
  background: red;
}
```

As you can see, it works fine !

Comment: This should be a comment, as it definitely is not an answer.

Comment: It means the author changes css rules via js?

Comment: my error, I meant <style> of course. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will point you in the right direction. I am not 100% sure I understood what you need. So if this is the case you can try appending a link tag with the css file url in it whenever you need. For instance you can trigger that script when you scroll X height or a click happened or whatever. For this case I am appending a style tag to the head every 2 seconds and then removing it so it won't keep appending every 2 seconds. Instead of style maybe you can do a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="promptFileSelectStyle.css"/>`
Hope this helps.

```js
function remover(){
 $(".style-tag").remove();
}

function x(){
    var style = $('<style class="style-tag">.columns {justify-content: space-around;} </style>');
  $('html > head').append(style);
  $(".parent").toggleClass("columns");
    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
remover();
x();
}, 2000);
});
```

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  
}
.box{
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">content</div>
  <div class="box">content</div>
  <div class="box">content</div>
  <div class="box">content</div>
  <div class="box">content</div>
</div>
```